# memset() does not work as expected

Tags: c++, memset

I am confused about the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

int main()
{
    int arr[3][4];
    memset(arr, 10, sizeof(arr));
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            std::cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090 
168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090 
168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090
```

I had expected running the above code would print

```
10 10 10 10
10 10 10 10
10 10 10 10
```

Can someone please explain the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: *memset() does not work as expected* -- memset works correctly.  It's up to you to provide the appropriate parameters.  If you wanted something that did anything remotely to what you're trying to accomplish, there is [std::fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)

Comment: The `memset` function has no idea that this is an array of `int`'s and so has no idea how to give them the correct pattern to decode as 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Becase `int` is more than one bytes long. `memset()` fills every byte with the given value. So, every byte of your 4-byte ints contains a 10.

Answer (score 3):

memset will treat the passed memory as a pointer to bytes.  Each byte will be set to 10, rather each int.

So you are printing out 0x0a0a0a0a, or 168430090, for each int.